# In ember-cli, how to keep debug statements in production builds?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When building in ember-cli using production with `ember build --environment 'production'`, by default `Ember.debug` statements that we use in *our* application code (that is, not *Ember*'s code) are stripped.

If I wanted `Ember.debug` to work in production builds, how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Does your config include defeatureify?

Comment: This seems a bit like a code smell, maybe you shouldn't use `Ember.debug` if you want call debug and have it log in prod.

Comment: @torazaburo no. Kingpin2k it is a strange use case, but (for now) a legitimate one.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new build definition `prodTest` and have it use all of your prod settings.  Then build `prodTest` instead of `production`

Comment: There's nothing in my 'development' environment that enables debug statements, and nothing in 'production' that removes them -- as far as I know this falls in the "magic" Ember territory.

Comment: production is a special build that does that all just based on it being the production build.  Anything other than production does a development build, so if you create a separate build with your production settings you will get a prod like build with the development vendor files.

Comment: To be clear -- I don't have production settings. I want all the things the production build gives me, *except* the removal of debug statements. Updating the question to reflect that I"m talking about *my* debug statements.